# Passing Values to AMPScript Variables from API

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

My email has a couple of AMPScript variables.
This email will be sent using API call. I don't want create profile attributes for these variables. Can I pass the values to these variables using the API call?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  They become personalization variables in the email context. So if you pass an attribute in your API call named `FirstName`, you can retrieve it like this:

```
%%[
var @firstName
set @firstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
]%%
Dear %%=v(@firstName)=%%,
```

You you don't have to create a corresponding Profile Attribute in order to use it.

Comment: Did this work for you?  If so, would you checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at our [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Hi @Adam, can I use the same solution to capture URLs? We have a password reset email where the reset URL is being via API. Will the same solution work for capturing URLs as well?